# How to use join with aggregate function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.4

I have 4 tables

**Table1**

```
id    | name    
1     | A
2     | B
```

**Table2**

```
id    | name1    
1     | C
2     | D
```

**Table3**

```
id    | name2    
1     | E
2     | F
```

**Table4**

```
id    | name1_id    | name2_id    | name3_id        
1     | 1           | 2           | 1
2     | 2           | 2           | 2
3     | 1           | 2           | 1
4     | 2           | 1           | 1
5     | 1           | 1           | 2
6     | 2           | 2           | 1
7     | 1           | 1           | 2
8     | 2           | 1           | 1
9     | 1           | 2           | 1
10    | 2           | 2           | 1
```

Now I want to join all tables with 4 and get this type of output

```
name    | count
{A,B}   | {5, 5}
{C,D}   | {5, 6}
{E,F}   | {7, 3}
```

I tried this

```
select array_agg(distinct(t1.name)), array_agg(distinct(temp.test))
from  
 (select t4.name1_id, (count(t4.name1_id)) "test" 
    from table4 t4 group by t4.name1_id
) temp
join table1 t1
on temp.name1_id = t1.id
```

I am trying to achieve this. Anybody can help me.

Comment: please tag the appropriate database system . You can't be using all the different database system at the same time

Comment: okay I edited my question

Comment: I tried this... select array_agg(distinct(rt.name)), array_agg(distinct(temp.test))
from  (select f.resource_type_id, (count(f.resource_type_id)) "test" from planner.resource_entity f join planner.resource_type ft 
on f.resource_type_id = ft.id group by f.resource_type_id) temp
join planner.resource_type rt  
on temp.resource_type_id = rt.id

Comment: actually I create a demo tables for question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the counts for every table separately and union the results:

```
select 
    array_agg(name order by name) as name, 
    array_agg(count order by name) as count
from (
    select 1 as t, name, count(*)
    from table4
    join table1 t1 on t1.id = name1_id
    group by name
    union all
    select 2 as t, name, count(*)
    from table4
    join table2 t2 on t2.id = name2_id
    group by name
    union all
    select 3 as t, name, count(*)
    from table4
    join table3 t3 on t3.id = name3_id
    group by name
    ) s
group by t;

 name  | count 
-------+-------
 {A,B} | {5,5}
 {C,D} | {4,6}
 {E,F} | {7,3}
(3 rows)
```

Comment: If I used column data type is  array in table 4 then.